# Ответ обработчика ajax запроса

Tags: ajax

В разных источниках читал что для любых аякс запросов считается хорошим тоном отдавать ответ обработчиком, пусть даже пустоту. Так вот тут возникли различные разногласия на работе, стоит ли это делать и в чем вообще смысл.

В общем, господа, хочется узнать ваше мнение по этому поводу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не возвращать никакой ответ, то обработчик аякс-запроса в итоге отвалится по тайм-ауту.  
Эта же ошибка (таймаут) может возникнуть, например, если клиент потерял связь с сетью.
лично я ВСЕГДА возвращаю ответ обработчику запроса, чтобы поймать внешние ошибки - таймауты и т.д.